# compile libffi as static library on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, makefile, raspberry-pi, static-linking, libffi

I'm trying to compile static library of libffi-3.2.1 with no success.

1. cd libffi-3.2.1
2. ./configure --prefix=/home/pi/libraries/libffi --enable-static --disable-shared
3. make

make output as follow:

MAKE armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf : 0 * all-all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
make 'AR_FLAGS=' 'CC_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS=-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math  -Wall -fexceptions' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2' 'CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=' 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c' 'INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644' 'INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c' 'INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c' 'JC1FLAGS=' 'LDFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS=' 'LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=' 'MAKE=make' 'MAKEINFO=/bin/bash /home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/missing makeinfo ' 'PICFLAG=' 'PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=' 'RUNTESTFLAGS=' 'SHELL=/bin/bash' 'exec_prefix=/home/pi/libraries/libffi' 'infodir=/home/pi/libraries/libffi/share/info' 'libdir=/home/pi/libraries/libffi/lib' 'mandir=/home/pi/libraries/libffi/share/man' 'prefix=/home/pi/libraries/libffi' 'AR=ar' 'AS=as' 'CC=gcc' 'CXX=g++' 'LD=/usr/bin/ld' 'NM=/usr/bin/nm -B' 'RANLIB=ranlib' 'DESTDIR=' all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/include'
Making all in testsuite
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/testsuite'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/testsuite'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
restore=: && backupdir=".am$$" && \
am__cwd=`pwd` && CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && \
rm -rf $backupdir && mkdir $backupdir && \
if (/bin/bash /home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/missing makeinfo   --version) >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
  for f in ../doc/libffi.info ../doc/libffi.info-[0-9] ../doc/libffi.info-[0-9][0-9] ../doc/libffi.i[0-9] ../doc/libffi.i[0-9][0-9]; do \
    if test -f $f; then mv $f $backupdir; restore=mv; else :; fi; \
  done; \
else :; fi && \
cd "$am__cwd"; \
if /bin/bash /home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/missing makeinfo     -I doc -I ../doc \
 -o ../doc/libffi.info ../doc/libffi.texi; \
then \
  rc=0; \
  CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd ..; \
else \
  rc=$?; \
  CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && \
  $restore $backupdir/* `echo "./../doc/libffi.info" | sed 's|[^/]*$||'`; \
fi; \
rm -rf $backupdir; exit $rc
/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want to install GNU make:
         http://www.gnu.org/software/make/
Makefile:1408: recipe for target '../doc/libffi.info' failed
make[3]: *** [../doc/libffi.info] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
Makefile:1596: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
Makefile:730: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]:  **[all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/libffi-3.2.1/armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf'
Makefile:607: recipe for target 'all-all' failed
make: *** [all-all] Error 2

What am I missing?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system`

Try to install `texinfo`:

`sudo apt-get install texinfo`